# How could I restart my Pong game and keep my score working?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been developing a Pong game for my first complete Python project, mostly using tkinter for most of the operations. However, I could not figure out how to restart the programme using the restart button I added without disabling the score counter in the top left corner.
The following text is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time
import pygame
import os, sys
import time

class Ball:

    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill='red')
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.hit_bottom = False
        self.score = 0

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.hit_bottom = True
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.score += 1

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 150, 10, fill='blue')
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 450, 750)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-Left>', self.stop_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-Right>', self.stop_right)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', self.turn_up)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', self.turn_down)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-Up>', self.stop_up)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyRelease-Down>', self.stop_down)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -3
    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 3
    def stop_left(self, evt):
        self.x = 0
    def stop_right(self, evt):
        self.x = 0
    def turn_up(self, evt):
        self.y = -0
    def turn_down(self, evt):
        self.y = 0
    def stop_up(self, evt):
        self.y = 0
    def stop_down(self, evt):
        self.y = 0
def restart ():
    global paddle, ball
    canvas.delete (ALL)
    paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
    ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')
    label = canvas.create_text(5, 5, anchor=NW, text="Score: 0", font=('Courier, 40'), fill='white')
    canvas.itemconfig(label, text="Score: "+str(ball.score))

def main ():
    global paddle, ball
    tk.update()

    paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
    ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')

    while 1:
        if ball.hit_bottom == False:
            ball.draw()
            paddle.draw()
        tk.update_idletasks()
        tk.update()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        if ball.hit_bottom == True:
            canvas.create_text(525, 300, text='Game Over', fill='red', font=('Courier', 60))
        canvas.itemconfig(label, text="Score: "+str(ball.score))

tk = Tk()
tk.title("User's Pong Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=1000, height=800, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.configure(background='black')
canvas.grid (row = 0)
label = canvas.create_text(5, 5, anchor=NW, text="Score: 0", font=('Courier, 40'), fill='white')
Button = Button(tk, anchor=NE, text = "Start Over", command = restart)
Button.grid(row=1, column=1)

tk.configure(background='white')

main ()
```

Comment: What is special about a PONG game that makes it unable to restart? What is restarting a PONG game?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
canvas.itemconfig(label, text="Score: "+str(ball.score))
```

with:

```
while 1:
    if ball.hit_bottom == False:
        ball.draw()
        paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    if ball.hit_bottom == True:
        canvas.create_text(525, 300, text='Game Over', fill='red', font=('Courier', 60))
    canvas.itemconfig(label, text="Score: "+str(ball.score))
```

inside the `restart` method.

---

How I debugged it:

1. Copied and run the entire code, tried the button, saw the score was statically 0
2. Searched for "Score" in the script to see where it is modified in the script
3. Noticed the lack of while, hence solved it.